# Can I draw shapes in a StringGrid cell without calling OnDrawCell?

Tags: delphi

I know how to draw shapes during a StringGrid.OnDrawCell event (by calling methods of a TCanvas object). When I do so, however, my UI constantly flickers and consumes memory as the draw event fires over and over.

The lines causing the flickering say things like 'if [condition1 for a given cell=true] then [draw a red circle in the cell].' (I can post the actual code, if desired.)

So, is it possible a custom method can do the same thing--tell a grid to draw a circle in a cell if a statement resolves to true?

Comment: OnDrawCell *is* the custom method that you do this in. Have you set DoubleBuffered to true? Can you post your drawing code? (I use custom drawing in StringGrids and DBGrids all the time without this being an issue.) Also, what Delphi version are you using?

Comment: Y'know what? I think this is all I needed ... the flickering seems to have stopped! I didn't know about the DoubleBuffered property. (I think it'll be good for me to read http://bcbcaq.freeservers.com/project_SG.html). ... Please post your reply as a response so I can accept it as answering my question. Thank you!

p.s. It's Delphi 2006.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't already, set `DoubleBuffered` to true. This causes all of the drawing to be done on an off-screen bitmap, and then the entire bitmap is drawn at once. It usually eliminates the flickering.

As far as custom methods to do the cell drawing, `OnDrawCell` *is* the custom method. :)

Answer (score 5):

The actual act of drawing is not what causes flickering. Flickering occurs when the window is repeatedly refreshed over and over. That usually means you are not managing the window correctly, for instance if you were calling `Refresh()` instead of `Invalidate()` when your drawing conditions change. Setting the `DoubleBuffer` property to true is like putting a band-aid on it. It hides the issue but does not really address the root problem.

Comment: +1 I think you should get to the root cause before covering it up with the band aid.

Comment: @Remy --  
Excellent point; thank you, Remy ... Clearly, I need to learn more about this. Right now I'm not calling Refresh, Repaint, or anything. The program just calls my OnDrawCell method a lot. In fact, I would love to be able to control when the method is called & have the event triggered only when I want it to. ... Is this doable? (I'm obviously ignorant about this topic. If you have a recommended web link I'd be happy to read and learn.) ... Thanks, as always!

Comment: The `OnDrawCell` event is triggered whenever Windows sends a `WM_PAINT` message to the grid to draw it onscreen.  You don't control that, the OS does.  There are many ways that `WM_PAINT` messages could be getting triggered - refreshing the window in code, dragging other windows over your grid, minimizing/maximizing the grid's parent window, etc.  When your drawing criteria change values, how are you signalling the grid so it can redraw itself with the new values?  Can you please show your actual code?

Comment: @Remy--The program's a game; the StringGrid is the board. Code in the OnDrawCell event says <pseudocode> if game.IsMySquare(aCol,aRow) then draw cell one way, else if game.IsYourSquare(aCol,aRow) then draw cell another way, else if game.IsInMyHand(aCol,aRow) then draw cell a third way </code> ... Other than OnDrawCell, the only other grid event handler is OnSelectCell. Grid also redrawn after player2's turn (when the program receives a string command received by a ClientWinSocket object), and after another component's OnClick event.

Comment: How do `IsMySquare()`, `IsYourSquare()`, and `IsInMyHand()` determine their criteria?  What do you do when that criteria changes?  What do you `OnSelectCell` and `OnClick` handlers actually do?  Where does your `ClientWinSocket` store the data it receives?  How are you "redrawing the grid after player2's turn"? Again, please update your original question to show your actual code.  It is important if you want help finding your drawing mistakes.

Comment: @Remy -- I figured out the issues, thanks to your direction. I think a call to grid.CellProperties[] within one of the if/then expressions in the OnDrawCell event was causing an endless grid drawing loop. When I changed that line the issue resolved itself. In addition, I found a typo! I meant to be referencing a variable called "aRect" and had written "Rect" instead. It didn't raise a syntax error--but certainly wasn't referencing the object I wanted to be referencing. D'oh! ... Thanks again for your help.

Comment: `TStringGrid` does not have a `CellProperties[]` property.